# WordPress Loop Display Content if Have Posts

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

I'm using the loop to pull a few custom posts to display on the site. I have a designated `<div>` to hold the posts. I've run into the problem when there are no posts to be pulled, the div box still displays with no content in it. How would I insert the code of my div container within the "if" statement so that the div is only created if there are posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <div>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      …
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You may find the [documentation on PHP's alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) useful

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) { ?>

  <div>

<?php } ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  ...

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) { ?>

  </div>

<?php } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Create a 404.php for your theme and [drop the `if (have_posts())` completely](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/do-we-still-need-to-include-a-if-have-posts-in-templates). You can start the loop with the `while` statement, and WordPress will use the 404.php if there are no posts.